# Error in generating plots inline in Rmd files

Tags: r, macos, ggplot2, r-markdown, google-drive-shared-drive

After updating to macOS 12.01 I am unable to generate any inline plots using ggplot in Rmd files that are stored in a Google Drive directory.

Any call to ggplot, e.g.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

Will fail with the error:

```
Error in dev.off() : 
  QuartzBitmap_Output - unable to open file '/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/.../.Rproj.user/shared/notebooks/-analysis/1/BB6A8C74064F89F4/cr5qmxwe04yxu_t/_rs_chunk_plot_001.png'
```

Executing this code in the console works fine, and I can knit the Rmd without errors. Changing the graphics backend to Cairo also fixes this, so it seems likely to be an issue with Quartz.

Moving the project file to a local directory also resolves this, but previous to macOS 12.01, R project integration with Google Drive would not cause these issues.

Xcode, XQuartz, R, and RStudio are all up to date.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: OP, this is definitely an issue with your Google Drive.  R and R Studio generally do not play very well when the libraries or projects are loaded from a shared drive.  Sometimes it works for me, sometimes not.  In the end, I use OneDrive / Google Drive to backup project files, but for the working environment, I don't work off anything that is synced.  I recommend the same for you.